# Android volley caching -How to display stale cached data when there is no network connectivity?

Tags: android, caching, android-volley

I have cached the response from the server based on the headers sent by the server . The value of max age is 180 s .From what I understand if any request is made for the same url after 180 s volley frameworks replaces the cache with the updated version of the data from the server . **I want to display the cached data when the network connectivity is not present  . How can I implement this using android volley???**

Comment: I  think you are already done .. turn off your network and check your response

Comment: I turned off my network n checked my response ..Before 180 s it fetches the data from the cache and my response code was 201 ..whereas after 180 s the data is not  fetched from the cache and the  void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)  is called .

Comment: you can handle by   VolleyError error = (VolleyError) err;

Answer (score 2):

in this case, hadle the network error and when it happens, get the data from the cache directly with mQueue.getCache().get(request.getCacheKey()), it will return the data if it's in the cache even if it's expired.